# Ensuring data persistence in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

I want to be sure whether my data gets persisted successfully in MongoDB. As in some cases MongoDB takes a fire_and_forget strategy, I want to specify Write Concern {w : majority, j : 1} at driver level which in my case is Mongoid.

Use-case :

I want to ensure my Users have unique 'nickname' and cannot signup violating the uniqueness.

I have already created an Unique Index on 'nickname' field.

Comment: and as I mention I want to set it in driver level. I know 'w' can be set through #with

Comment: Have you tried `session.command(j: 1)`

Comment: Yup but no luck. Found a configuration file name mongoid.yml (/config/mongoid.yml) where I can configure moped driver.

Answer (score 2):

For replica sets you can use the following configuration, as is described at http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#replica:

```
consistency: :strong
```

Together with that, you'd want to have safe mode on, as is described at http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/tips.html#safe_mode:

```
safe: true
```

It does not look like you can set MongoDB's `w` parameter like this, but you can set it on a Band document operation—that's going to be per query though:

```
Band.with(safe: { w: 3 })
```

You can also do it per session with:

```
Band.mongo_session.with(safe: { w: 3 }) do |session|
    session[:artists].find(...)
end
```

Comment: Ya, thank for the help Derick. like specifying w parameter can we also  specify j parameter to be sure that my writes are actually persisted?

Comment: I don't know, their documentation doesn't say anything about it. But the idea is that with ``w: "majority"`` that should not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer:
Consider using multiple data storage options.   Far too often people are jumping on the NoSQL bandwagon,  when it isn't necessary.   If you need guranteed writes you should use a relational database, or consider a hybrid such as orientDB.  Lack of guaranteed writes is one of the big reasons why solutions such as MongoDB scale so well.

Comment: With some drivers (like PyMongo) not only I can ask Mongo server to acknowledge my writes but also to ensure me if writes are logged to an on-disk journal to guarantee write durability (Journaling is the term they use). So there is a very rare chance of data loss.

Comment: Again you have the opportunity for data loss, which is the crux of my answer

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate that. But in some cases like when you have a tolerance limit you can accept that. Suppose you failed to persist a comment on a blog post and it happens once in a million. Okey lets not go into a debate on SQL vs NoSQL. I just want to know if setting 'j' parameter is possible in mongoid or not

Comment: "Again you have the opportunity for data loss", care to explain a bit better? I am unsure how full, to disk, write concern will lose data unless the server downs before it gets the data entirely and I am afraid having a relational database or a band wagon tech like orientDB won't save you from that, this is a fundamental flaw...if only computers used their mind reading powers to know what we wanted to say instead of only knowing what they recieved...

Comment: Unnecessary and unhelpful rant not really relevant to the question of how to achieve something using a specific tool.

Comment: @AndyTriggs You should enrich the community by providing an answer yourself.  It is relevant because it is theoretically impossible to do unless some computer scientist has figured this out in recent history.

Comment: The post author appears to have found a way to do what he was trying to do, using config/mongoid.yml.